# Some save issues in CRUD editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is the code in my controller section:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
  if (id == null || _context.Combo == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }
  var combo = await _context.Combo.FindAsync(id);
  if (combo == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }
  ViewData["CurriculumId"] = new SelectList(_context.Curriculum, "CurriculumId", "CurriculumCode", combo.CurriculumId);
  return View(combo);
}
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</div>
```

When I click save in the edit section, it still saves to the database but it doesn't return to home and shows an error like this:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
> reference CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , object )

i added the parameter but it still doesn't run.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-id="@Model?.CurriculumId"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You must have 2 action and after save data ,Must Redirect to home or index action .Example : https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/create-edit-view-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Why it will return to home? I don't find any about redirect to home in your code, It will just return to edit page.